# Last six months on columns mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using a query to show last 6 months grouped and SUM by "CODIGO"

simplified :

```html
WHERE pg.fecha_pago >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

full query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d220c/1/0

result

```html
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| ID PRO        | FECHA                     | CANTIDAD      | CODIGO        |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+----------------
| 1553          | 2021-07-05                | 6             | E1100811      |
| 1553          | 2021-07-05                | 12            | E1100751      |
| 1552          | 2021-08-05                | 4             | E1000764      |
| 1565          | 2022-01-09                | 6             | PRUEBA        |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

i need to keep grouped by CODIGO, but separate sum in months on columns.

Expected

```html
    +-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | CODIGO    | MONTH6 | MONTH5 | MONTH4 | MONTH3 | MONTH2 | MONTH1 |
    +-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | E1100811  |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |
    | E1100751  |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |
    | E1000764  |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |
    | PRUEBA    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |   x    |
    +-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Where MONTH1 is the actual month and MONTH2 the previous month, and so on.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT
  sR.codigo,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 5)) MONTH6,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 4)) MONTH5,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 3)) MONTH4,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 2)) MONTH3,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 1)) MONTH2,
  SUM(sR.cant_ser * (YEAR(CURDATE()) * 12 + MONTH(CURDATE()) - YEAR(pg.fecha_pago) * 12 - MONTH(pg.fecha_pago) = 0)) MONTH1
FROM db1_pagos pg
LEFT JOIN db1_servicios sR ON (sR.id_pro = pg.id_pro)
WHERE pg.fecha_pago >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND pg.status_pago = 'SALDADO'
GROUP BY sR.codigo
```

Comment: Perfect, now I only have to do the navigation for months, but this is great, thanks!